# Data type to handle decrypting data - as method param data type

Tags: c#, encryption

On several of our AJAX endpoints, we accept a string and immediately in the method, we try to decrypt the string into an int. Seems like a lot of repetitive code.

```
public void DoSomething(string myId)
{
  int? id = DecryptId(myId);
}
```

Where DecryptId is a common method (in the base controller class)

I would like to create a class that does all this for me and use this new class as the data type in the method argument (instead of `string`) and then a `getter` that returns the decrypted `int?`

What's the best way to do this?

**Edit:**

Here's my implementation that is working.

```
public class EncryptedInt
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
}

public class EncryptedIntModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("bindingContext");
        }

        var rawVal = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        var ei = new EncryptedInt
        {
            Id = Crypto.DecryptToInt(rawVal.AttemptedValue)
        };
        return ei;
    }
}

public class EncryptedIntAttribute : CustomModelBinderAttribute
{
    private readonly IModelBinder _binder;

    public EncryptedIntAttribute()
    {
        _binder = new EncryptedIntModelBinder();
    }

    public override IModelBinder GetBinder() { return _binder; }
}
```

Comment: If you're using Asp.Net MVC, I believe the best way would be to create an `EncryptedString` type and register a model-binder for it.

Comment: I was about to suggest an extension method on `string`, but I guess you only want the decryption to happen once (not once per method/property call).

Comment: @Heinzi, yes, I only want to have the decryption happen once.

Comment: @zaph, it is decryption.

Comment: @haim770, is this what you had in mind: create a type (i.e. class) that represents the data
public class EncryptedString {
public string encrypted {get;set;}
public int? id {get;set;}
}
and then create a model binder like the following:
http://aboutcode.net/2011/03/12/mvc-property-binder.html
and in the BindProperty, decrypt string and assign to int? prop?

Comment: @Ed.S., Yes indeed. Yet, since the whole point of your changes is to avoid repetitive code, you better register the model-binder globally in the model-binders collection rather than apply the `[EncryptedInt]` attribute for each method than expects `EncryptedInt` parameter.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution. Since it answers the question, please add it as an answer (it's OK to answer your own question) instead of adding it to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my implementation that is working.

```
public class EncryptedInt
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }

    // User-defined conversion from EncryptedInt to int
    public static implicit operator int(EncryptedInt d)
    {
        return d.Id;
    }
}

public class EncryptedIntModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("bindingContext");
        }

        var rawVal = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        var ei = new EncryptedInt
        {
            Id = Crypto.DecryptToInt(rawVal.AttemptedValue)
        };
        return ei;
    }
}

public class EncryptedIntAttribute : CustomModelBinderAttribute
{
    private readonly IModelBinder _binder;

    public EncryptedIntAttribute()
    {
        _binder = new EncryptedIntModelBinder();
    }

    public override IModelBinder GetBinder() { return _binder; }
}
```

... and in Global.asax.cs in the Application_Start method (in case you want it global for all EncryptedInt types instead of using Attribute on each reference) ...

```
// register Model Binder for EncryptedInt type
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(EncryptedInt), new EncryptedIntModelBinder());
```